# How to return to jQuery dialog from post action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**Hello**,

I'm learning MVC through developing a simple web app. and I have a problem with using jQuery Dialogs.

I have a model with index/create/edit views and actions. The edit is done through a *partial view in a jQuery dialog*. so far the dialog loads the partial view and submits it without problems. **The problem is when the data entered in the edit form is wrong no error messages returned and the dialog is closed right away.**

**Here is my index view**

```html
@model IEnumerable<HomeManager.Models.Expense>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
</div>
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure to delete?
    </p>
</div>

<h2>Expenses</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "lnkEdit btn btn-primary btn-sm linkButton", role = "button"}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "lnkDelete btn btn-primary btn-sm linkButton", role = "button" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Create", new HomeManager.Models.Expense()); }
</p>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/HandMade/Dialogs.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/HandMade/SideBar.js"></script>
}
```

**And here is my Edit view**

```html
@model HomeManager.Models.Expense

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Expense", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Now here is my JavaScript which is in a separate .js file**

```js
    $(".lnkEdit").click(function (e) {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".ui-dialog-title").html("Update Expense");
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        //show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "black");
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("color", "white");
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $("#editForm").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Finally these are my Edit get/post actions**

```
    // GET: /Expense/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Expense expense = db.Expenses.Find(id);
        if (expense == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        //return View(expense);
        return PartialView(expense);

    }

    // POST: /Expense/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Title,Amount,ApplicationUserId")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(expense).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //return View(expense);
        return PartialView(expense);
    }
```

What I want is when I enter Wrong data on the edit form and click the OK button the dialog does not close and the error messages appears beside the fields with errors.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your code is submitting the form (`$("#editForm").submit();`) so you immediately leave the page and redirect to `Index()` method or return a new view if `ModelState` is invalid. I assume your wanting to submit the form using ajax and stay on the same page?

Comment: And because your dynamically loading the form, you will not get any client side validation unless you reparse the validator after you update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran across a very similar issue.  My solution was to set a hidden variable in the form on the ASPX page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="showDialogFlag" id="showDialogFlag" value="@VariableFromController" />
```

And then use jQuery's ready function to check the value in the hidden field to decide whether to display the dialog:

```
<script>
    function showOopsDialog() {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Oops!',
            width: '580px;'
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#showDialogFlag").val() === 'y') {
            showOopsDialog();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say. Would you explain more please.

Comment: The general idea is to set a flag in a hidden form variable in the HTML to indicate whether to display the dialog when the page loads (`showDialogFlag` in this case).  Then use the jQuery `ready()` function to check the hidden form variable and show the dialog if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my Own question:

I updated the post Edit action to return this when no errors

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Title,Amount,ApplicationUserId")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(expense).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Update Successful"); // Here is the update
        }
        return PartialView(expense);
    }
```

And Update the Ok button in the dialog to be like this

```js
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                //$("#editForm").submit();
                $.post('/Expense/Edit', $("#editForm").serialize(), function (data) {
                    if (data == "Update Successful") {
                        $("#dialog-edit").dialog("close");
                        window.location = "/Expense/Index";
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#dialog-edit").html(data);
                    }
                }, "html");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```